# A reduction of 3-CNF down to 2-CNF for boolean satisfiability

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, satisfiability, conjunctive-normal-form

Could you please review the following candidate solution for the boolean satisfiability problem?

It is known that 2-CNF has a polynomial solution.

Now consider we have a 3-CNF (AFAIK, it's proven that every boolean formula can be reduced to 3-CNF in polynomial time).

If no 2 clauses have the same pair of variable (like `a1` and `a2` in one clause, and `-a1` and `a2` in another clause), then the formula can be simply assigned `true`/`false` values for the variables in the middle of each link of the chain, like:
`(a1 v a2 v a3)(-a3 v -a4 v a5)`etc. - here we simply assign `a2=1` and `a4=0`, and no matter what the values of the other variables are, the formula is satisfiable already.

Now consider some 2 clauses have the same pair of variables, possibly negated. In each step of the program we find such 3-clauses and transform them into implicative 2-clauses as follows.

`(a1 v a2 v a3)(a2 v a3 v -a4)` and `(a1 v -a2 v -a3)(-a2 v -a3 v -a4)` - here `a2` and `a3` is the pair and we transform this into 2-CNF with replacements `x = (a2 v a3)` and `x = (-a2 v -a3)` respectively.

Next, consider `a2` and `a3` participate in 3-CNF as follows:
`(a1 v a2 v -a3)(-a2 v a3 v a4)`
Then we can replace `x=a2 v -a3` and `y=-a2 v a3`. We get 2-CNF `(a1 v x)(y v a4)` that can be transformed into implicative form. However, it lacks 4 more implicative relations between `x`, `-x`, `y` and `-y`. Let's show how these are related. Here `+` denotes  a XOR operation.

```
a2 v -a3 | -a2 v a3 | a2 | a3 | x+y | x*y |
-------------------------------------------
   1           1       0    0    0     1
   0           1       0    1    1     0
   1           0       1    0    1     0
   1           1       1    1    0     1
```

From the truth table, we can infer that `x*y = x+y+1`

Consequently,

```
x * -y = -y
y * -y =  0
-x * x =  0
-x * y = -x
-x * -y = 0
```

From the first and the fourth equations above we can infer 4 implicative clauses in total:

```
x * -y = -y   =>  (-y -> x) and (y -> -x)
-x * y = -x   =>  (-x -> y) and (-y -> x)
```

By analogy, we can reduce 3-CNF clauses into 2-CNF implicative clauses for `(a1 v a2 v a3)(-a2 v a3 v a4)` replacing `x=(a2 v a3)` and `y=(-a2 v a3)`, and for `(a1 v -a2 v -a3)(a1 v a2 v a3)` replacing `x=(-a2 v -a3)` and `y=(a2 v a3)`.

So the problem of boolean satisfiability seems to have been reduced polynomially into 2-CNF BSAT problem that has a polynomial solution in its turn.

UPDATE: let me finish showing how case `x=(a2 v a3)` and `y=(-a2 v a3)`, and case `x=(-a2 v -a3)` and `y=(a2 v a3)` get handled.

Truth table #2 for `x=(a2 v a3)` and `y=(-a2 v a3)`:

```
a2 v a3 | -a2 v a3 | a2 | a3 | x+y | x*y |
-------------------------------------------
   0          1       0    0    1     0
   1          1       0    1    0     1
   1          0       1    0    1     0
   1          1       1    1    0     1
```

Equations:

```
x*y =  a3 }
          } => x*y = x+y+1 
x+y = -a3 } 

x * -y = -y
y * -y = 0
-x * x = 0
-x * y = -x
-x * -y = 0
```

Consequences:

```
x * -y = -y   =>  (-y -> x) and (-x -> y)
-x * y = -x   =>  (-x -> y) and (x -> -y)
```

Finally, for case `x=(-a2 v -a3)` and `y=(a2 v a3)`:

Truth table #3:

```
-a2 v -a3 | a2 v a3 | a2 | a3 | x+y | x*y |
-------------------------------------------
   1          0       0    0    1     0
   1          1       0    1    0     1
   1          1       1    0    0     1
   0          1       1    1    1     0
```

Equations:

```
x * y = x + y + 1
x * -y = -y
y * -y = 0
-x * x = 0
-x * y = -x
-x * -y = 0
```

Consequences:

```
x * -y = -y   =>  (-y -> x) and (-x -> y)
-x * y = -x   =>  (-x -> y) and (x -> -y)
```

UPDATE2:

After the above transformations, no pairs stay in the formula, e.g.

`(a1 v a2 v a3)(-a1 v a4 v a5)(-a2 v -a4 v a7)(-a3 v -a5 v -a7)`.

In general, this case is `(a1 v a2 v ...)(-a1 v a3 v ...)...`. So we take two 3-clauses where the same variable appears straight and negated, and then we substitute `x = a1 v a2` and `y = -a1 v a3`.

Truth table:

```
a1 v a2 | -a1 v a3 | a1 | a2 | a3 | x*y | x+y |
-----------------------------------------------
   0    |     1    | 0  | 0  | 0  |  0  |  1  |
   0    |     1    | 0  | 0  | 1  |  0  |  1  |
   1    |     1    | 0  | 1  | 0  |  1  |  0  |
   1    |     1    | 0  | 1  | 1  |  1  |  0  |
   1    |     0    | 1  | 0  | 0  |  0  |  1  |
   1    |     1    | 1  | 0  | 1  |  1  |  0  |
   1    |     0    | 1  | 1  | 0  |  0  |  1  |
   1    |     1    | 1  | 1  | 1  |  1  |  0  |
```

We get similar equations as for pairs:

```
x  *  y = x + y + 1
x  * -y = -y
-x *  y = -x
-x * -y = 0
```

Consequences:

```
x  * -y = -y   =>   (-y -> x) and (-x -> y)
-x *  y = -x   =>   (-x -> y) and (-y -> x)
```

Update3:
If no variable appears both straight in one 3-clause and negated in another 3-clause, then we simply assign to each variable `true` if it appears straight only and `false` if it appears negated only.

So it seems that P=NP.

Comment: In your no-pairs case, what happens with a formula like $$(a_1 \vee a_2 \vee a_3) \wedge (\lnot a_1 \vee a_4 \vee a_5) \wedge (\lnot a_2 \vee \lnot a_4 \vee a_7) \wedge (\lnot a_3 \vee \lnot a_5 \vee \lnot a_7)$$ ?

Comment: @NicholasViggiano, good question, thanks! I didn't see such a case, let's try if a solution similar to a Horn formula works...

Comment: @NicholasViggiano, huge thanks to you, we've found how to solve such cases and I'm editing the question.

Comment: @NicholasViggiano, please, see my update #2.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not clear on what happens with formulas like $$(a_1 \vee a_2 \vee a_3) \wedge (\lnot a_1 \vee \lnot a_2 \vee a_4) \wedge (a_2 \vee \lnot a_3 \vee a_4)$$ assuming $a_4$ is used again later. Do not your $x$ and $y$ trip over each other?

Comment: @NicholasViggiano, thanks for noticing that. There are 8 implications over 5 variables. Let me try to see if that is sufficient.